# Cannot log into MySQL workbench server - unknown database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

After dropping a schema in MySQL workbench and attempting to re-create it (a process I have done many imes, it is just an easy way to clear out the database so that hibernate can recreate it), I suddenly got this error for the first time and now I cannot do anything with MySQL workbench. Any help?

> Cannot Connect to Database Server Your connection attempt failed for
> user 'root' to the MySQL server at localhost:3306: Unknown database
> 'bookstore'

It then makes me check that MySQL is running on localhost, port 3306, user root has rights, password is correct, etc. This is all correct. I know the database is unknown because I dropped it, but I am not sure why that is causing an issue now when all I want is to be able to log in to the server. I tested the connection via settings for the server connection and it is actually able to connect fine. I have done this before many times with no issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you set bookstore as the default schema on start up?

Comment: I am fairly confident I did not, but regardless the issue has seemed to resolve itself. No clue what I did to fix it.